# Jersey REST date @XmlAttribute causing an illegal argument exception

Tags: java, xml, date, jersey, illegalargumentexception

I have a Jersey REST web service which takes in a POSTed XML string. I have entities for each element of the XML to split them up into objects.
When I pass a Date parameter e.g. inspectionDate="12/02/2012" I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 12/02/2012
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseAndSetYear(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:400)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$5.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:271)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$5.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:273)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:241)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:481)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:148)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:124)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:97)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:393)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:43)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:126)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:173)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:163)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:612)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:603)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:309)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:590)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my XML string:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
    <user userName="Test.Test" userID="43">
      <client>
        <site>
          <building>
            <location>
              <asset assetID="293">
                <inspection assetID="293" inspectionDate="12/02/2012" inspectionRef="inspection_ref_89158">
                 <comments>Test</comments>
                  <assessedBy>Natasha Allsopp</assessedBy>
                  <assessed>false</assessed>
                  <notAssessedReason>Access Hatch Padlocked<notAssessedReason>
                  <acceptable>true</acceptable>
                  <remedialActionRequired>false</remedialActionRequired>
                  <remedialActionID>0</remedialActionID>
                  <flowTemperature>0.0</flowTemperature>
                  <returnTemperature>0.0</returnTemperature>
                  <temperature1MinHot>0.0</temperature1MinHot>
                  <temperature2MinCold>0.0</temperature2MinCold>
                  <showerHeadsPresent>4</showerHeadsPresent>
                  <showerHeadsCleaned>0</showerHeadsCleaned>
                  <showersNotCleanedReason></showersNotCleanedReason>
                  <storedWaterTemperature>0.0</storedWaterTemperature>
                  <incomingMainsTemperature>0.0</incomingMainsTemperature>
                  <anyLeaks>false</anyLeaks>
                  <sludgePresent>None</sludgePresent>
                  <corrosionPresent>None</corrosionPresent>
                  <flotsamPresent>None</flotsamPresent>
                  <turnoverCheck>Good</turnoverCheck>
                  <conditionofTank>Good</conditionofTank>
                  <goodFittingLidPresent>false</goodFittingLidPresent>
                  <lidVented>false</lidVented>
                  <ventScreened>false</ventScreened>
                  <overflowPresent>false</overflowPresent>
                  <insectScreen>false</insectScreen>
                </inspection>
              </asset>
            </location>
          </building>
        </site>
      </client>
    </user>
```

And here is a snippet of my entity class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"inspectionDate"})

public class Inspection {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected Date inspectionDate;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String inspectionRef;

        public Date getInspectionDate() {
        return inspectionDate;
    }

    public void setInspectionDate(Date inspectionDate) {
        this.inspectionDate = inspectionDate;
    }
}
```

If I use the following XMLJavaAdapter:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [] threw exception [com.sun.jersey.api.container.MappableContainerException: java.io.IOException: Error unmarshalling JAXB object of type "class dao.jpa.User".] with root cause
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There are two properties named "inspectionDate" 
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.Date dao.jpa.Inspection.getInspectionDate()
        at dao.jpa.Inspection
        at protected dao.jpa.Inspection dao.jpa.Asset.inspection
        at dao.jpa.Asset
        at protected dao.jpa.Asset dao.jpa.Location.asset
        at dao.jpa.Location
        at protected dao.jpa.Location dao.jpa.Building.location
        at dao.jpa.Building
        at protected dao.jpa.Building dao.jpa.Site.building
        at dao.jpa.Site
        at protected dao.jpa.Site dao.jpa.Client.site
        at dao.jpa.Client
        at protected dao.jpa.Client dao.jpa.User.client
        at dao.jpa.User
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.util.Date dao.jpa.Inspection.inspectionDate
        at dao.jpa.Inspection
        at protected dao.jpa.Inspection dao.jpa.Asset.inspection
        at dao.jpa.Asset
        at protected dao.jpa.Asset dao.jpa.Location.asset
        at dao.jpa.Location
        at protected dao.jpa.Location dao.jpa.Building.location
        at dao.jpa.Building
        at protected dao.jpa.Building dao.jpa.Site.building
        at dao.jpa.Site
        at protected dao.jpa.Site dao.jpa.Client.site
        at dao.jpa.Client
        at protected dao.jpa.Client dao.jpa.User.client
        at dao.jpa.User
Class has two properties of the same name "inspectionDate"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.Date dao.jpa.Inspection.getInspectionDate()
        at dao.jpa.Inspection
        at protected dao.jpa.Inspection dao.jpa.Asset.inspection
        at dao.jpa.Asset
        at protected dao.jpa.Asset dao.jpa.Location.asset
        at dao.jpa.Location
        at protected dao.jpa.Location dao.jpa.Building.location
        at dao.jpa.Building
        at protected dao.jpa.Building dao.jpa.Site.building
        at dao.jpa.Site
        at protected dao.jpa.Site dao.jpa.Client.site
        at dao.jpa.Client
        at protected dao.jpa.Client dao.jpa.User.client
        at dao.jpa.User
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.util.Date dao.jpa.Inspection.inspectionDate
        at dao.jpa.Inspection
        at protected dao.jpa.Inspection dao.jpa.Asset.inspection
        at dao.jpa.Asset
        at protected dao.jpa.Asset dao.jpa.Location.asset
        at dao.jpa.Location
        at protected dao.jpa.Location dao.jpa.Building.location
        at dao.jpa.Building
        at protected dao.jpa.Building dao.jpa.Site.building
        at dao.jpa.Site
        at protected dao.jpa.Site dao.jpa.Client.site
        at dao.jpa.Client
        at protected dao.jpa.Client dao.jpa.User.client
        at dao.jpa.User

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:177)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:393)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:43)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:126)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:173)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:612)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:309)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:590)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting the `two properties...` exception is that in your real class you added the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)` annotation on the get method instead of the field that has the `@XmlAttribute` annotation.

Comment: Yes I was doing that also, I thought the `DateAdapter.class` wasn't being called when I put the `@XMLJavaTypeAdapter` on the `XMLAttribute`. However, it turned out it was working but because I was missing a / on one of the my XML elements it was causing a bad request. Thank you for your help, your website proved to be very helpful *thumbs up*

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass inspectionDate="2012-02-12" instead of inspectionDate="12/02/2012" in your xml input and check again ? If you want to use an alternate format then you will need to leverage an XmlAdapter

Comment: When I change the date format in my xml to 2012-02-12 I get a 400 Bad Request status. If I set it to either 12/02/2012 or 2012/02/12 I get the error above

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the date formatting issue when using the DateAdapter was due to my XML string. There was an element tag which was missing a / in it's end tag e.g.  `<notAssessedReason><notAssessedReason>` should have been `<notAssessedReason></notAssessedReason>`